# If Matching, Skip Writing Value to Csv

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to write some strings in a list to a csv file. I'm stepping through the list, and writing it to the csv file, but when I find a match within the 2 lists, I do NOT want to write the value in the list to the csv file. Could anyone help me with the syntax to skip writing a list's value to a csv if that value matches another value from a separate list? My code is below if you want to see where my syntax went wrong.

```
import csv

listOfAppIDs = []
#open file to read each line and add each line in file to an array. These are our appID's to search
with open('filelcation/listAppIDs.txt', 'r') as fi:
    for line in fi:
        listOfAppIDs.append(line.rstrip('\n'))
listOfAppIDs.sort() #alphebetically sort list
print listOfAppIDs

alreadyReviewedAppIDs = ['youseemore','streampix','streamaudio','spotify','speedtest','soundcloud-base','smartsheet-base','samsung-updates','print-over-ms-smb','exp','dicom','pop3','x11','echo','webdav','ustream','telnet','skydrive-base','rsync','outlook-web','nfs','ms-office365-base','itunes-appstore','apple-appstore','aim-mail','discard','time','akamai-client','bomgar','cisco VPN','DHCP','IBM-Clearquest','Ironmountain-Connected','MS-SCOM','MS-SSTP','SCCP','SNMPV3','WCCP','XDMCP','secureserver-mail','teamviewer-base']
print alreadyReviewedAppIDs

i=0
i2=3
with open ('filelocation/outputAppIDsToDo.csv', 'wb') as outputFile:
    writer = csv.writer(outputFile, delimiter=',',)
    for item in listOfAppIDs:
        if(i%14==0):
            i2 +=1
        #for item2 in alreadyReviewedAppIDs:
        #   if (item2==item):
        #       break
        writer.writerow([i2, item])
        i += 1
```

Comment: do you mean doing `if item in listOfAppIDs or item in alreadyReviewedAppIDs:continue`?  If it is in either list then continue to the next item

Comment: if `item` from `listOfAppIDs` is equal to `item2` from `alreadyReviewedAppIDs` then don't execute statement `writer.writerow([i2, item])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this part

```
with open ('filelocation/outputAppIDsToDo.csv', 'wb') as outputFile:
    writer = csv.writer(outputFile, delimiter=',',)
    for item in listOfAppIDs:
        if(i%14==0):
            i2 +=1
        if item in alreadyReviewedAppIDs: # if match
           continue # skips the item
        writer.writerow([i2, item])
        i += 1
```

you were pretty close, the `continue` statement jumps to the next iteration of the forloop 
but the `break` statement will only stop the current loop and continue the code after it(the loop)